# using stripslashes() discriminately

Tags: php

My php application uses stripslashes() to deal with magic_quotes but I only want it to remove slashes that magic_quotes is putting in, because the user is allowed to supply a \ with his input.

Answer (score 8):

`stripslashes` does not indiscriminately remove slashes.

If magic quotes is on, then it'll escape slashes, replacing `'\'` with `'\\'`, and `stripslashes` should undo magic quotes' escaping correctly, replacing `'\\'` with `'\'` to get you back what the user entered.

I think you probably just want something like this:

```
// Ripped from the PHP manual (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php)
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $lastname = stripslashes($_POST['lastname']);
}
else {
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
}
```

At the end of that code `$lastname` should not have any slashes except those the user entered.

On another note, magic quotes are a security issue, and are deprecated in newer versions of PHP (see [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)).

Answer (score 2):

Using magic_quotes_gpc is a bad idea anyway, it's officially deprecated as of 5.3 and *gone* as of PHP 5.5.  More importantly (and immediately), it encourages weak security because it doesn't really *do* anything useful that couldn't be done by mysql_real_escape_string or prepared statements or stored procedures.

If you can get rid of it, please do...

Answer (score -1):

Try rolling your own encoding/decoding functions, like so:

```
function doEncode($string){
     return addslashes(str_replace("\","\\",$string));
}

function doDecode($string){
    return str_replace("\\","\",stripslashes($string));
}
```